# Can i access background running apps on my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way i can access the apps running on the iphone and either cancel them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open URLs with special schemes assigned to other apps from your own app, and it'll cause those apps to open. For example if another app allowed you to call URLs like `someapp://myurlhere`, you could attempt to connect to that URL and that app will open instead of Mobile Safari.

You can't manipulate other processes from your own app though; Apple doesn't allow that. Your app is restricted to its own process and directory in the iOS file system. That means you can't kill other processes from your own code. (I'm guessing you *technically* can with jailbreaking, but I don't have experience with jailbreak stuff. Doing this means Apple won't let your app into the App Store.)